# Different output from macros and function definition

Tags: c, function, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define prod(a,b) ((a>b)?a*a:b*b)

int prod1(int a,int b){
       return ((a>b)?a*a:b*b);
}

int main(){
        int p=0,q=-1;
        int p1=0,q1=-1;
        printf("%d ",prod(p1++,q1++));
        printf("%d ",prod1(p++,q++));
        return 0;
}
```

Output is:
1
0

Why is it different? How is the macros definition different from the function definition and why does it produces different results? Shouldn't all 2 outputs be equal to 0?

Comment: What is what different?  Different from what?

Comment: Modifying an unsequenced variable more than once is undefined behavior.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in the first case (when using the macro). Expand the macro out manually and you'll see that you have unsequenced accesses and modifications to the `p` and `q` objects.

Comment: Answering this question is like promoting laziness.

Comment: @haccks You learn fast. :P

Comment: @Abhinav C or C++? Pick one.

Comment: @H2CO3; Lession from yesterday's answer :(

Comment: Who is upvoting this question ?

Comment: With all due respect, I think we all have been bitten by this bug once. I know I have. It's seems obvious now, but it's subtle when you aren't thinking too much about the preprocessor. The #define min/max version is a more common one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the macro

```
#define prod(a,b) ((a>b)?a*a:b*b)
```

a and b are referenced more than once. So

```
prod(p1++,q1++)
```

becomes

```
(p1++ > q1++) ? p1++*p1++ : q1++*q2++
```

Note that this is very different than calling the function

```
prod1(p1++, q1++)
```

which only increments `p1` and `q1` **once**. And does so predictably.

Comment: Oh, right. Should have expanded it first before asking. My bad.

Comment: @haccks No actually should have expanded it manually, then wouldn't have even searched it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The macro's arguments `a` and `b` are copied as text into the expanded body of the macro, so `prod(p1++,q1++)` expands to `((p1++>q1++)?p1++*p1++:q1++*q1++)` which is obviously different to what the function evaluates.

In standard C it is undefined if a single object is modified more than once between successive [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), so the macro causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the code that is compiled after the pre-processor has finished its jobs:

```
int prod1(int a,int b){
       return ((a>b)?a*a:b*b);
}

int main(){
    int p=0,q=-1;
    int p1=0,q1=-1;
    int p2=0,q2=-1;
    printf("%d ",((p1++>q1++)?p1++*p1++:q1++*q1++));
    printf("%d ",prod1(p++,q++));
    printf("%d ",(p2>q2)?p2*p2:q2*q2);
    return 0;
}
```